# ¿Como cambiar texto con formato a texto plano en PHP?

Tags: php, html, postgresql

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto de filtrado de datos, y se me presento una cuestión si podrían darme alguna guía.

Tengo datos en almacenados en `postgres` los cuales extraigo a través de una consulta pero entre ellos una columna la cual tiene texto en cursivas y negritas las cuales necesito cambiar a un solo formato.

A continuación se muestra:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Acá el fragmento de código para la consulta

```
$cbba = pg_query($conexion, "SELECT id, name, longitud, latitud, observaciones FROM cbba where id = 21");

while ($row1 = pg_fetch_row($cbba)){


echo $row1[0]." : ".$row1[4];
echo "<br>";
```

Aca el valor de `$row1[4]`, el cual se encuentra dentro de `<span class="html-attribute-value">`

```
<span class="html-attribute-value">Casa en Venta en Cochabamba, 
     -  6    
ó Una de las mejores y mas tranquilas zonas residenciales de 
Quillacollo, Villa Moderna, a pocos minutos del Cine Center y de la 
Av. Blanco Galindo y a solo 3 cuadras del nuevo prado de Villa Moderna.
 ó Hermosa casa de estilo minimalista a estrenar. 
La misma cuenta con amplio jardín y 6 habitaciones, acabados y 
materiales de primera calidad, excelente iluminación natural e 
iluminación LED, entre otros detalles, que les brindaran a ti y 
a tu familia la comodidad y el estilo de vida que se merece. 
  Espacioso living comedor / escritorio / cocina con 
cajonería completa y espacio para comedor de diario / baño de visitas. 
 1 Suite con vestidor y baño privado con jacuzzi / 
3 dormitorios con roperos empotrados / baño compartido  2 : 
2 dormitorios / baño compartido / amplia terraza 
 Churrasquero techado/ lavandería / baño de servicio / 
amplio jardín / garaje para 3 movilidades con puerta automatizada 
 á Agua, Luz, Alcantarillado y Gas 
!     ,    !</span>
```

---

También utilice `strip_tags` para eliminar las etiquetas (gracias por la ayuda con la función) pero tampoco pudo eliminar:

```
$cbba = pg_query($conexion, "SELECT id, name, longitud, latitud, observaciones FROM cbba where id = 21");

while ($row1 = pg_fetch_row($cbba)){
$mostrar = strip_tags($row1[4]);
echo $row1[4];
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
echo $mostrar;
}
```

Utilizando `strip_tags` obtuve esta respuesta:
En 1ra respuesta esta la consulta,
En la 2da esta utilizando strip_tags

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradecería mucho alguna guía de como se podría lograr cambiar el tipo de formato (quitar las cursivas y las negritas) y guardarlo en otra variable.

De todas formas seguiré investigando, gracias.

Comment: Tu pregunta no se entiende. ¿Cómo es ese texto, es HTML u otro? Dependiendo del código fuente, podrás extraer lo que produzca las cursivas/negritas del contenido y guardarlo de nuevo.

Comment: Perdón aclarando el texto esta en una base de datos fue descargado y guardado en tal, viendo desde la consola de postgres este texto esta igual tal como se ve en la imagen que es de la consulta (tiene negritas y cursivas).

Comment: No, en la consola o en la base de datos directamente, deberías ver el texto fuente y ver si esas negritas las producen etiquetas HTML como `<b>` o `<strong>` igualmente si las cursivas las produce `<i>` o `<em>` etc. Sin saber lo que las produce no podrás limpiar el código. Además, debes explicar dónde vas a usar esa información, no sea que estropees el contenido y luego no puedas usarlo en el destino final.

Comment: Los tags html forman parte del dato en tu bd?

Comment: No ese es el problema cuando hago un `echo` en la base de datos directamente no se encuentra ningún tag revisando en la tabla tampoco utilizando `echo "<pre>" . $row1[4] . "</pre>";` igual solo muestra el texto ya con negritas y cursivas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que necesitas hacer se denomina [transliteración](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transliteraci%C3%B3n)

> Las transliteraciones, en el sentido estricto, se utilizan para reflejar la forma exacta en que una determinada palabra se representa en la lengua original

Para llevar a cabo esto, podemos utilizar la función [`iconv`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.iconv)

> Convierte un string a la codificación de caracteres indicada
> [...]
> Si se añade el string **//TRANSLIT** a out_charset, se activa la transliteración. Esto significa que cuando un caracter no puede ser representado en el set de caracteres final, se puede aproximar a uno o varios caracteres parecidos.

Entonces, suponiendo que la cadena esta en `UTF8`, podemos hacer la transliteración a `ASCII` para obtener una cadena convertida a un sistema de caracteres mas básico.

#### Ejemplo:

```
<?php

$text = '!     ,    !';
echo iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $text);
// Resultado: !Esta es la casa que buscas, agenda una visita ya!
```

Comment: Gracias efectivamente utilice strip_tags para eliminar las etiquetas sin obtener un resultado favorable.

Comment: Gracias esa función realmente funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Podrias eliminar los tags usando una expresion regular de esta forma:

```
$re = '/<[^>]*>/';
$str = '<span>String de ejemplo con tags HTML</span>';
$subst = '';
$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
echo $result;
```

El resultado seria **String de ejemplo con tags HTML**